# Where is the optimal place to put an API link in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to figure out the asset pipeline in Rails 3 to play around with the Google api

```
"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
```

**1st question.** Is it best to place that link in views/layouts/application.html.erb or in assets/javascripts/application.js

**2nd question**

If I'm writing a javascript function that gets its arguments from a form id in a view, where do I put that javascript function?  Does it go directly in assets/javascripts/application.js or are there other places to put the javascript..

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but [this RailsCasts video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline) may help you understand the asset pipeline better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you even **can** put the maps API into the `application.js`. At least it didn't work for me last time I tried.

The general idea of application.js is that all content that is referenced there will be automatically minified and compressed in a production environment. Since that's not possible for the maps API I guess you should put it into your `views/layouts/application.html.erb`

Also note that you may not want to include the maps API on all your pages. You could either define a layout that is itself referencing `application.html.erb` or you use a partial or you use a [content_for](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-content_for) to include the page only in the places you need it.

One thing I've done in the past (there may be better ways) is to define a placeholder in the head section of the layout and then use that to inject scripts that are only required on a small number of pages. Like this:

`application.html.erb`:

```
<head> 
other stuff
<%= yield :scripts %>
...
</head>
```

And inside your view that requires google maps:

```
<% content_for :scripts do %>
<script type="text/javascript" ..... ></script>
<% end %>
```

Anything inside the content_for block will be output where you placed your `<%= yield :scripts %>`.

Comment: could you explain in more detail how to use a partial and content_for to include the API only in selected places?